# Forbid direct method calls

Tags: c#, security, methods

I have business layer with classes which inherit from some BusinessBase. The main CRUD-like methods have a custom RequiresPermission(activityId) attribute. Those methods are called from a custom WCF service, so I can check user permissions there and throw exception if user has no permissions to execute the operation or if the method to call does not have RequiresPermission attribute set. This happens completely transparently for other programmers in my team - if they forget to assign permissions, the method call fails.

The problem is that one business class might directly call some method (maybe even from some other business class). I would like to forbid any method from executing if it does not have RequiresPermission attribute set on it or if the action with activityId is not available to the currently authenticated user.

Is there any way I can enforce those checks to avoid security holes because of some lazy programmer who forgot to call security checks inside of the method?

Comment: Have the security checks set a thread-local variable indicating that they have been done, have every business layer method check whether that's been done, and clear the threadlocal when the call finishes. (This *might* have weird interactions with `await`/`async` though, I don't know how thread-locals behave in the face of that feature.)

Comment: Alternately, only make it possible to get an instance of `BusinessBase` with an explicit object representing the permission context to begin with, which would have to be done for every call, instead of just making it a singleton.

Comment: You could investigate using an Aspect framework (like PostSharp, Afterthought) - it provides several ways of interacting with methods at run time - the OnEntry method would be perfect for your needs as you could check the attribute of the method and the current user context as the method is being called. See http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.1/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.1.chm/html/M_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect_OnEntry.htm for example.